# Existence of partition of unity such that the functions and their derivatives vanish at infinity

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, paracompactness

Like the title says, suppose $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a locally compact  space without isolated points and $\left \{ U_i \right \}$, ${i \in \{1,\cdots ,n \}}$ is an open cover of $K$. Are There  a partition of unity on $K$ subordinate to $\left \{ U_i \right \}$ consisting of  functions $\{ f_{i}\}_{i \in \{1,\cdots,n \}}$ such that:

$$
f_i \in C_0^{1}(K,[0,1]) \quad \text{for all $i \in \{1,\cdots,n \}$}?
$$

where $C_0^{1}(K,[0,1])$ is the banach space consisting of all continously differentiable functions $f$ such that $f, f'$ vanish at infinity (provided for example the max norm).

So far I've seen : [Existence of a partition of unity with uniformly bounded derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27366/existence-of-a-partition-of-unity-with-uniformly-bounded-derivatives)

Is there any article, book that take partitions of unity with this properties? perhaps I just need to follow the main proof? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This is trivially false in the case $n=1$.  Are you really sure you want to require the $f_i$ to be indexed by the same set as the $U_i$?

Comment: It is not needed, although all references conclude the existence of the functions indexed by the number of elements of the finite covering

Comment: More generally, a non-compact space can *never* have a finite partition of unity consisting of functions that vanish at $\infty$, since then their sum will also vanish at $\infty$.

Comment: You're correct, what if $K$ is compact then? (in general  im trying to see what conditions must $K$ 
meet so that I can make this partition of unity.

Comment: If $K$ is compact then every function vanishes at $\infty$ so you can just take any smooth partition of unity subordinate to the cover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, such a partition of unity never exists if $K$ is not compact.  Indeed, the sum $f_1+\dots+f_n$ would also vanish at infinity, but that is impossible since this sum must be equal to $1$ which does not vanish at infinity.

If you drop the requirement that the $f_i$ are indexed by the same set as the $U_i$, though, then such partitions of unity do exist.  First, since $K$ is locally compact, you can refine your open cover to an open cover $\mathcal{V}$ by precompact open sets.  Then you can take any smooth partition of unity subordinate to $\mathcal{V}$.  Since each element of $\mathcal{V}$ is precompact, each function in this partition of unity has compact support in $K$ and so in particular it and its derivative vanishes at infinity.

Comment: Both comments are so detailed, thank you.